# Help with Matrix Equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

So I am looking at [this paper](http://www.mcgrating.com/references/ref02.pdf) and I am lost on equation 28.  Section 4A tells the size of all components, but it looks like none of the dimensions add up.  So I guess I am asking how the author uses the sizes given to find that there are 4N+2 equations.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take equation $20$ and replace the *infinite* vector $\mathbf \xi$ (that was of $N \rightarrow \infty$) with the *finite* vectors $\gamma_N$ from equation $18$ and $19$. These vectors have a dimension of $2(2N+1)$.

In equation $20$ the $m$-dimension of matrix $\mathbf T$ accords to the dimmensions of the corresponding vectors $\xi$ (it says *"defined like vector $\xi$..."*), however consequently, now when substituted by $\gamma_N$ the matrix $\mathbf T$ will follow and get the $m$-dimension of $(4N+2)$.

This is also in accordance with the matrix form (paragraph after equation $20$):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
       A & B           \\[0.3em]
       C & D           \\[0.3em]
      \end{bmatrix}$$

---

With regard to equation $28$ following your question:

$$\underbrace{\mathbf {b^0}}_{4N+2\rightarrow 2N+1} = \dots+ \underbrace{M'}_{(4N+2)\times P}  \underbrace{\mathbf B}_{P}$$

what I understand is that despite of $M'$s dimmension because of the conditions of inequalities $27$, iff $r_q^0$ satisfying $27$ a row would remains, all other rows will cancel so you will have only $2N+1$ equations left.

This is how I understand the author yet and hope make physically sense.

Comment: Yes, but if $\bf b_0$ is 2N+1 and $\bf B$ is P, how does equation 28 produce 4N+2 equations with 4N+2 unknowns?

Comment: So how would i be able to solve for $\bf b0, B$

Comment: I unfortunately do not follow

Comment: Okay.  So for simplicity, say N=1.  I will have 6 equations.  I will have 3 $b_0$, lets say 2 $b_{Q+1}$ and 1 B?

Comment: Do I treat them as if it was A, B, C and there are linear equations and then use the conditions to seperate them?

Comment: Yes. Hope I understood you correctly. The author is just confusing and want to say thousand things in one paragraph.

Comment: Yeah I am beyond confused, but I think you were able to clear that up for me

Comment: I dont think I can help further, this can not be done by formula, it is really the numeric section you have to run the whole system and see how it reduces. According to author the $4N+2$ system reduces nummerically under the given conditions $27$.